# View content ot TRESTRequest before sending?

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

So if I have prepared a REST Request, is there a way that I can view the output of it before sending for debugging purposes?

So:

```
LRequest.Client := LClient;
LRequest.Method := rmPOST;
LRequest.Resource := AUTH_PATH;
LRequest.Accept := 'application/json';
// required parameters
LRequest.AddParameter(ExCode, AuthCode, pkGETorPOST);
LRequest.AddParameter(ExRedirectURI, RedirectionEndPoint, pkGETorPOST);
LRequest.AddParameter(ExGrantType, ExAuthorizationCode, pkGETorPOST);
LRequest.AddParameter('Autorization', ExAuthParam, pkHTTPHEADER);

LRequest.Execute;
```

might yield:

```
POST https://oauth.platform.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic UTM0dVBvRDIwanp2OUdxNXE1dmlMemppcTlwM1d2
    NzRUdDNReGkwZVNTTDhFRWwxb0g6VEh0WEJlR3dheEtZSlVNaFhzeGxma1l
    XaFg3ZlFlRzFtN2szTFRwbw==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: oauth.platform.com
Body: grant_type=authorization_code&
code=L3114709614564VSU8JSEiPkXx1xhV8D9mv4xbv6sZJycibMUI&
redirect_uri=https://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect
```

Comment: `TRESTClient` internally uses platform dependent implementation of `THTTPClient` to setup and execute the request. For instance Windows implementation of `THTTPClient` is `TWinHTTPClient`. It uses [WinHTTP library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/about-winhttp) which is responsible for crafting the request bytes and sending them over the wire. At this point you don't have access to those bytes. Use tools like Fiddler or [Postman echo service](https://docs.postman-echo.com/) for debugging.

Comment: Fiddler is working out.  Thanks!