# DELPHI - Get JSON POST Request for debugging

Tags: json, rest, delphi

I am new to REST in Delphi and I am wanting to view the content as text that is about to be posted.  When attempting to use TJson.ObjectToJsonString I get a Stack Overflow error.

The code I am using is:

```
var
  RestClient: TRestClient;
  RestRequest: TRestRequest;
  Param: TRESTRequestParameter;
begin
  Memo1.lines.clear;


  RestClient := TRestClient.create(nil);
  RestRequest := TRestRequest.create(nil);

  RestClient.Params.clear;
  RestRequest.Client := RestClient;
  RestRequest.Params.clear;
  RestRequest.ClearBody;

  RestRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;

  RestClient.BaseURL := 'http://my.server/MyService';
  RestClient.ContentType := 'application/json';
  Param := RestClient.Params.AddItem('my-webservice-password', 'MySecret');
  Param.Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;

  RestClient.Params.AddItem('Param1', 'MyFistParam');
  RestClient.Params.AddItem('Param2', 'MySecondParam');
  RestClient.Params.AddItem('3rdParam', 'true');

  Memo1.lines.text := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(RestClient);  // <<<<< Stack Overflow here

  RestRequest.Execute;

end;
```

Can someone please advise why this would be creating a stack overflow, or alternatively what I should be doing to view the JSON request that is about to be submitted?

Thanks & Regards

Adam

Comment: You shouldn't call `ObjectToJsonString()` on a `TRestClient`. It should only be called on a user object (that you want to serialize to JSON).

Comment: See also recent (unanswered) question - [View content ot TRESTRequest before sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470098/view-content-ot-trestrequest-before-sending). Delphi REST library is not capable of inspecting the traffic. You need to use external tool.

Comment: The stack overflow is probably caused by a circular reference between objects. Serialization typical works well for data objects with a linear nested structure. As soon as a child references back to its parent, the serializer will keep going back and forth between them.

Comment: Thanks all for responding. So in the above instance, would I be better off to use TidHTTP as opposed to Rest if I want to inspect within Delphi itself?

Comment: You can also make a http-server and post the data to that server. Then when you handle the action server side, you can read the received request and inspect ir...

Answer (score 0):

Try using REST Debugger from tools menu . it is easier and show the results directly .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).